# Permission denied in dlopen() API

Tags: c++

I am opening a shared object in my program, using dlopen() API. But getting below error:

```
cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible that dlopen is not able to relocate the text segment of your shared library. In such case we can change the permission to dynamically select the relocation. you need to execute the following command with root permission to change the permission.

```
chcon -t texrel_shlib_t <your lib path here.>
```